# What is the proper plural of "reputation"?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

> Vote Down requires 125 reputation

Shouldn't it be "reputations"? Why or why not?

Comment: Whom did you try to down-vote? ;)

Comment: My friend who only recently started to use SE and was hesitant to share his one post that got upvotes in fear of being downvoted by me. I'm a good friend so I tried my best.

Comment: No-one seems to be saying exactly what seems obvious to me - in OP's context, it's just an abbreviated version of *"reputation **points**"*. Just because the actual noun (points) isn't explicitly stated doesn't mean we have to treat the (effectively adjectival) *reputation* as a "pseudo-noun" requiring plural inflection.

Comment: Colloquially, [lolspeakily](http://speaklolspeak.com/), you could say *reps* or *repz*.

Comment: This question obviously polarises opinions (it's currently got 5 upvotes and 4 downvotes). Two points arising: a) I think it's disappointing not one of those 4 downvoters added a comment explaining their reasoning; b) I've raised the issue on meta as [Should ELU offer more guidance on Question Downvoting?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2858/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think many of the downvotes were cast because of my less than stellar original title of the question "Is this sentence correct". Since I've been using SE for over three years now, I can understand that this was indeed not a good title. At the lowest point I saw it had a total of -3 points. As a result of KitFox correcting the title many other upvoters stepped in to "undo" the downvotes from others - a phenomenon frequently observable on SE sites.

Comment: @fish: If that were the case you might hope the downvotes disappear (after you make an edit, people can cancel or even reverse their votes). You still have -4 (but +9 right now, so the net total is rising!). For all I know, the original 4 *all* reversed their votes and 4 more downvoted. Or they never looked back, and all new votes have been favourable (it's certainly ***way*** more popular than the question it prompted me to ask on meta! :)

Comment: As far as I know, the users won't get a notification if a downvoted question was edited. So while your reasoning seems plausible, I think it's unlikely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Reputation* in this instance is being used as a mass noun, and mass nouns do not normally take a plural. It is somewhat unusual in this case that there is no count noun to serve as the measure word, i.e. we don't say "125 points of reputation" by analogy with "125 grains of rice". Nonetheless, the formulation given above is what is normal and idiomatic for this scenario.

There are other words which exhibit this same pattern:

- Getting to level two requires 5000 experience.
- The Vorpal Sword costs 300 gold.

All of the examples that come to mind here are related to technology or gaming. I don't know if this is an actual trend, or just selection bias based on what's in my brain.

Comment: I'm going to disagree that the case with Reputation is the same as the video-game case for "gold". In the video game the units are arbitray, so saying "coins" is not helpful. In the case of "reputation" you have one reputation, but it is measured in "points". The sentence as shown is either wrong, or more charitably, a short-form, which is allowed because people are forgiving when it comes to computer user interfaces messages.

Comment: In the first example experience is simply a shorthand for experience points.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 I disagree that it is short form, I believe it is as a result of how reputation is used on Stack Exchange - as a currency.

Comment: Well, a commodity at any rate

Comment: I think this is hopelessly wrong! "Mass noun" - [a noun that normally cannot be counted](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mass_noun). "Reputation" is an [attribute - *a characteristic or quality of a thing*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/attribute), that happens to be capable of being "graded" by number. No different to "miles per gallon", say, except there we *always* specify the units. Or "star" *(5 star movie, 4 star hotel, 2 star general)* where the unit is assumed, but context-specific. In OP's usage, **125** is just the adjectival quantifier for the assumed unit "reputation *points*".

Answer (score 7):

Reputation is not the unit, its the object being quantified. *Technically*, it would be

> Vote Down requires 125 points of reputation

But this is awkward and we all understand that reputation is an arbitrary number with no real unit. Saying "How much reputations do you have" would be akin to saying "how much strengths do you have" or "how much sauces do you have?"

Comment: I can't quite go with that. The object being modified is the implicit *[ammassed collection of] **points***. Which is *also* modified by the adjective *"reputation"*, telling us which particular *kind* of "points" we're talking about here.

Answer (score -3):

Well it looks like you can say reputations :

The book 
investigates how reputations historically have been made and un-made (from a study 'Surveillance & Society' by Daniel Neyland Oxford University)

Comment: Here, you're using it to mean many people's reputations. Each person still has his own reputation, not reputations. Reputation is a common noun in your sentence, whereas it is an abstract noun in the OP's sentence

Comment: sorry.. I thought the question was the plural of reputation...Indeed in every language, not only english, one person has his own reputation

Comment: @mlwacosmos, the flip side of "one person has his own reputation" is "most people don't have their own reputations"; ie "each person..." may be what you meant.