# Use of "golds" when "gold" is countable in context?

Tags: grammatical-number

I'm wondering whether "golds" is an acceptable usage, if "gold" is countable in the context of the usage

For example, an online game where you have countable gold, or when you find a finite amount of gold, for example, "32 golds"

Comment: By definition, it is (in answer to your title /first question). A count noun usage must have a(t least one) plural form. This may be invariant (10 aurochs) or an inflected form (10 oxen). //  But here, you're confusing grammatical and etical countness. _10 pieces of gold_ describes an etically countable situation but _gold_ has not got a count usage in this sense.

Comment: Related: [What is the proper plural of “reputation”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76130)

Comment: Also related, I think: [The computer has 48GB memory (or memories?)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29756)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope.

If you find 32 gold pieces, you earned "32 gold".

There are two ways to interpret it... you can either pretend that "gold" in this usage is a word that can be used as both singular or plural, much like "sheep". Or you can look at it as a sort of "counter word" as sumelic mentions in the comments.

Here are some examples of actual use in the gaming world:

[League of Legends Forum:](http://forums.na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2537440)

> Riot, why the Nexus gives 50 gold when destroyed?
>   I read somewhere that way back when the game was starting, every building gave +50 gold. They just left it in the nexus code for nostalgia.

From a [card game](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/index.html/_/game-of-thrones/game-of-thrones-strategy/the-road-to-winterfell-chapter-pack-review-r1540):

[image: Trading with the Pentoshi Card - Game of Thrones card game]

As a counter word, it explains the similar treatment of other words in the gaming world either as it relates to stats or collectable items in game:

- +5 strength
- 200 wood
- -10 health
- 50 meat

In each case, you can infer a missing plural either between the number and the counter word or after it:

- +5 strength [points]
- 200 [pieces of] wood
- -10 health [points]
- 50 [pieces of] meat

Similarly, 32 [pieces of] gold.

Comment: It is not alike to sheep. Sheep is a noun where the plural is sheep as well. Gold does not have plural.

Comment: The point is, that it **is** the plural in this case.

Comment: I wonder if it should be counted as a plural, or if it is some kind of singular noun being used with a counter. For example, I could imagine saying I have "25 life" or "25 resistance" in a game. The normal plural form of "life" is "lives," but it is not used. I guess you could say "life" is an alternative zero-plural form, but I would be inclined to call it the singular form.

Comment: @sumelic that's an interesting way to think about it...

Comment: @Catija have a look at my answer with the dictionary definition. It's a mass noun, there is no plural. **Gold does not have a plural, thus your liking it to the word sheep is not only misleading but incorrect.** Contrary to sumelic's examples the usage of gold for gold coins is not an invention of video games.

Comment: @Helmar I can read just fine... just because something is in a dictionary doesn't mean that it allows for **all usage** of the word. The question is specifically about gaming... the answer I give specifically relates to gaming and is based on actual examples of use along with my own personal experience.

Comment: @Helmar: "gold" as a mass noun referring to gold coins is certainly not an invention of video games. However, I don't think it was often used **with just a preceding number** historically. (I don't know; do you have any historical examples like that?) I think it's been more common to say something like "He had much gold" = "he had many gold coins" than "He had 32 gold" = "He had 32 gold coins."

Answer (score 4):

Those who are insisting that 'gold' is a mass noun and so never has a plural are wrong. Many mass nouns have a plural certain circumstances, most commonly when the meaning is "kind of x". So something like "There are several different golds in the colour chart" is perfectly cromulent.

In the case of 'gold', there is a much more prominent use of the plural: where 'gold' stands for 'gold medal'. "We won 2 golds and 7 silvers".

Where they are right is that 'gold' meaning 'gold coins' or 'gold pieces' does not generally take a plural (or is used as plural).

Comment: gold when referring to gold medals is a count noun: **4 [COUNT NOUN] short for gold medal.** [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gold) Not a mass noun. As Edwin helpfully edited my answer gold **in the sense** of gold coins is a mass noun.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. Accepted Catija's as s/he provided usage examples in the gaming context. I would argue "golds" can be used in the gaming context, but for the time being, went with "gold"

Answer (score 1):

Gold is a mass noun in this sense: [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gold)

> gold NOUN [MASS NOUN]
>   3 Coins or other articles made of gold

Thus, linguistically, *the word **gold** when used in the meaning of gold coins cannot be counted*. No counting, no plural.